# mysql - selecting after sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have a table that looks like

```
 ID |value
 --------
 1  |  10
 --------
 2  |  30
 --------
 3  |  20
 --------
 4  |  20
 --------
 5  | 10 
 --------
```

I sort it in descending order and selected first two rows using LIMIT.

so the selection query returns :

```
 --------
 2  |  30
 --------
 3  |  20
 --------
```

Now I want to select the second two rows in the same way of sorting so the result should be :

```
 --------
 4  |  20
 --------
 1  |  10
 --------
```

How can I do this ?

*The query must be a dynamic query* 
I mean after selection those two rows I should select the next two rows and so on until the end of the table.

*Important Declaration*

The query must take last ID from the previous selection and generate the next two automatically. Sorry, I forget to say that at the first time I posted the question.

Comment: I edited the question so you can understand what the problem is :)

Answer (score 2):

use `LIMIT 2, 2`

Read more about LIMIT here: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: and after 5 times of selection ? It should work to the end of the table so the query should be more dynamic

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OFFSET` portion of the [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

```
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2;
```

This will allow you to limit the results starting after the specified offset, in this case - after the second row.

**UPDATE** (dynamic query?)
To make the select/offset dynamic, you'll need to handle that portion in PHP. I'm assuming that you're pulling the records, doing something with them, then pulling the next set? If this is correct, you can just keep a counter for how many iterations you've done:

```
$offsetCounter = 0;
// start your loop, based on whatever you need (for, while, etc.)
    $limit = 'LIMIT 2 OFFSET ' . (2 * $offsetCounter++);
    // append `$limit` to the end of your query
    $query = 'SELECT ID, value FROM yourTable ORDER BY value DESC ' . $limit;
```

**UPDATE #2** (dynamic query, without `OFFSET`)
If you can't use `OFFSET`, or at least a counter to implement it with, but you *can* use the ID of the last record retrieved you can add that into your `WHERE` clause (I would also recommend sorting by the ID field too in that case).

Something like the following should work (update to use prepared-statements if necessary):

```
$lastIdSelected = 0;
// start your loop
    $query = 'SELECT ID, value FROM yourTable';
    $query .= (($lastIdSelected != 0) ? ' WHERE id > ' . $lastIdSelected : '');
    $query .= ' ORDER BY value DESC, id ASC LIMIT 2';
    // execute query, do your work, etc.

    // on your last record, do:
    $lastIdSelected = $row['ID'];
```

Of course, this also follows the format of my first-update with the `OFFSET` variable. You can modify this to *not* use a temp-variable to store the last ID, but it may end up being the same amount of work either way.

Comment: Now you get it. but the problem is I don't have the ability to use this  $offsetCounter .. all I have got is the ID of the last selection's second row

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OFFSET

```
$sql = 'SELECT ID, value FROM myTable LIMIT 0, 2 ORDER BY value DESC;
```

The above will give you the first two rows.

```
$sql = 'SELECT ID, value FROM myTable LIMIT 2, 2 ORDER BY value DESC;
```

This will give you the next two rows

More information on LIMIT can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)